# Eclipse ALL my project no longer shows up under Package Explore

Tags: java, eclipse

I had to reset my system because some files where not getting unlock.  After I reset it and  ran eclipse, the package was empty and had a error message (I did not write it down and forgot what it said).
I exit eclipse and re ran it, there is no error message and all the projects are gone from package explore.
Also all the project on that drive have the same issue. (worspacr stored on another drive works fine).

All the files are there, eclipse is not seeing them,

Comment: What does _reset my system_ mean?

Comment: If the files are still there try to File --> import... --> Existing projects into workspace. Choose your project folder. Then you supposed to see it again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me and this is what I did on Windows version of Eclipse Mars.  In Project/Package explorer window **->** Click the Drop down Menu (Triangle button) **->** Top Level Elements **->** Select '**Projects**'

Hope this helps!!